# Not being able to read statusCode when sending a request

Tags: express, node-request

I am developing an api with node.js but i am having trouble with one of my routers while sending a request in postman.

The following is my router:

```
    //@route   GET api/profile/github/:username
    //@desc    Get user repos from github
    //@access  public

    router.get('/github/:username', (req,res)=>{
        try {
            const options = {
                uri: `https://api/github.com/users/${req.params.username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${config.get('githubClientId')}&client_secret=${config.get('githubSecret')}`,
                method:'GET',
                headers:{'user_agent': 'node.js'}

            };

            request(options, (error, response, body) => {
                if(error) console.error(error);

                if(response.statusCode !== 200){
                    res.status(404).json('No Github profile found');
                }

                res.json(JSON.parse(body));
            });

        } catch (error) {

            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        }
    })
```

So in this route i am trying to find a github username that is being passed via the uri.

This is the request i am sending:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/profile/github/<GITHUB_USERNAME>
```

but when i send my request i get the following error in my VSC console.

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')

if(response.statusCode !==200){
```

Comment: `api/github.com` typo? FYI, [request is deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142), has been for over 3 years and should not be used

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here:

First, `https://api/github.com/users/xxx` should be `https://api.github.com/users/xxx`.  You put a `/` where there should have been a `.` .

And, in fact, your very code should be showing the error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api'
}
```

which is telling you that the domain `api` was not found.  It's looking for that domain because of the error in your URL.

Second, this error is complicated in your code because if you get an `error` returned from the `request()` library, then the callback arguments `response` and `body` are invalid, but you try to use them.  The physical request did not succeed so there is no response or body.

You can amend your code like this:

```
router.get('/github/:username', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const options = {
            uri: `https://api/github.com/users/${req.params.username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${config.get('githubClientId')}&client_secret=${config.get('githubSecret')}`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'user_agent': 'node.js' }

        };

        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                res.status(500).json({code: error.code, message: "Network error communicating with github"});
                return;
            }

            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                res.status(404).json('No Github profile found');
                return;
            }

            res.json(JSON.parse(body));
        });

    } catch (error) {

        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});
```

This handles the error by returning a 500 status and creating an error object to send back to the client.  It also adds `return` statements after sending a response so the following code doesn't execute and try to send other responses.

---

**NOTE:** The `request()` library has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated) since early 2020 and will no longer be developed with new features.  It is NOT recommended for new code.  You can use newer, promise-based libraries such as `node-fetch`, `got` or any of the others listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  In the most recent versions of nodejs, you can use the built-in version of [fetch](https://fusebit.io/blog/node-fetch/?utm_source=www.google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=none).